# How to keymap arrowkeys to alt + [ijkl] in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xbindkeys

I have already tried xbindkeys + xvkbd

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Left]'"\
m:0x8 + c:44\
alt + j

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Down]'"\
m:0x8 + c:45\
alt + k

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Right]'"\
m:0x8 + c:46\
alt + l

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Up]'"\
m:0x8 + c:31\
alt + i
```

Although it works for some situations
but it doesnot work in terminal or files

What could be better solution?